# Increase clickable area of button in ion-nav-bar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app with a navbar. In this navbar are buttons that are a little bit bad to touch. So I want to increase the touch area of the buttons. I tried this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-stable background-main-color" align-title="center">
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
  <div class="navbarIconArea" ng-click="test2()">
     <button class="button searchIcon background-main-color icon-color" ng-click="test()"></button>
  </div>
</ion-nav-buttons>
[...]
</ion-nav-bar>
```

But `test2()` is just called when the button is clicked exactly and `test()` is invoked, too. The div works when it is outside of an `ion-nav-bar`.

Any idea how to fix this or how to increase the area otherwise?

CSS (50px just to test, will be 10px):

```
.navbarIconArea {
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is not that I both functions are called when clicking on the button. It is that `test2()` is not called when clicking on the area around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the button div itself a link. Nest the div tag within an a tag.

```
<a href=#><div></div></a>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Now I can click on the div, but only the left border works. Clicking on the rest of the div has no effect... Do you may know why?

My ion-nav-buttons content now looks like this: `<a href="#">
        <div class="navbarIconArea" ng-click="test2()">
           <button class="button searchIcon background-main-color icon-color" ng-click="test()"></button>
        </div>
      </a>`

Comment: try to use padding in css to match with <a> tag  it will work dont forget to upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I needed to set the z-index of the a tag. Now it works!! :D

Answer (score 2):

What I could understand from your problem is. You have a `div` which has a `button` and you want to invoke the function `test()` only on button click and `test2()` only when the div is clicked. Now your problem is that when ever you click the button the div is also getting clicked. Actually this is the expected behaviour. The button is inside the div and when you click on the button you are actually clicking the div too. So **click of button is also equal to click of div**. So both your functions are getting executed.

**Solution** is Give enough margin between your button and div. So use this CSS, `button.searchIcon{margin:20px}`, this will set 20px space between button and the div.

So now **one problem is fixed**, you can `click around the button and it will be a div click`.

Now another problem still exist. Even if you click the button the div is clicked, So the solution would be to remove the `ng-click` on the button, So now you will just have the div click, so inside this div click what you do is see if the click happened on the button or not (since you have not added jquery tag i am not giving you any example code, you can check it in jquery), if the click was on button then dont execute `test2()` execute `test()`. else if it was not on the button execute `test2()`. So this will require a new function which will warp this logic and the toggling of the calls. and point to this new function in `ng-click` of the div.

Comment: Thx for your answer! But this is not the problem. Sorry, this was my mistake. 
My problem is that the div is not clickable. When I touch the area around the button the function `test2()` is not called. It doesn't matter that both functions are invoked when clicking on the buttons.